# react-router Switch and 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't want to use Switch, because I want to take advantage of having multiple Components that uses the current url to update themselves.
But I have to use Switch, because I want a 404 page.

Of course I'm using react-router v4. Anybody can point me to a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest routes inside another route component

```
<Switch>
  <Route component={Main} path="/"/>
  <Redirect  component={404} />
</Switch>
```

Then inside Main Component

```
  <Route component={Compp1} path="/"/>
  <Route component={Compp2} path="/"/>
```

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I can.